# How can I forward ports in Windows?

Tags: networking, powershell, port-forwarding, windows-11, remote-access

This post is going to be related [to this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1112677/how-to-connect-to-a-computer-with-custom-winrm-port-using-windows-admin-center) one I made on Serverfault that never got any response.

Since I still haven't got any solution to my original problem, I decided to take care of it with port forwarding.

Windows has native [port forwarding features](http://woshub.com/port-forwarding-in-windows/) such as

```
netsh interface portproxy
```

or [native SSH port forwarding](http://woshub.com/ssh-tunnel-port-forward-windows/), but I need help apply them to my situation.

I have 2 computers, I want to control one of them using Windows Admin Center, from the other one, when I'm not at home, over Internet.

my home computer is behind a VPN which can have specific open ports, so I set up WinRM on the home computer to use HTTPS and a custom port that my VPN allows to be open.

on the remote computer, I installed my SSL certificate, and I can connect to my home computer, over the Internet using HTTPS and PowerShell remoting with custom port.

so far so good, everything works. the problem is that I don't want to use PowerShell remoting, I want to use Windows Admin Center because of its GUI, but WAC only works with the default WinRM HTTPS port which is 5986.

I need a solution to make Windows Admin Center work with my custom WinRM port instead of the default 5986 port. my home computer can't use the default 5986 port because it's closed by the VPN, the VPN only allows specific ports such as 56555 and that's what the WinRM HTTPS listener is set to.

I tried many port forwarding rules on the remote computer, using netsh command like this:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=54896 listenaddress=192.168.2.2 connectport=5986 connectaddress=192.168.2.1
```

but none of them worked for me. I think because what I need to do should apply to outgoing traffic, but what I see in those guides are about incoming traffic.

I need help figuring out how I can do this with native built-in Windows tools I mentioned or other tools that might be there that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Why is this tagged PowerShell? This is not a PowerShell code issue. Which is what we are here for.

Comment: There is issue with my PowerShell code, otherwise I wouldn't run into problem with it.

Comment: You are not showing any PS code. You are using a Windows executable/command ```netsh - C:\Windows\system32\netsh.exe``` potentially in a PS console session, and that does not make in PS code. So, ```netsh.exe``` (cmd.exe is in control here, not PS). Running *.exe from PS, under the covers call cmd.exe to run *.exe. Running *.exe in the PS console must be properly formatted. [As fully documented here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx).